# Apache won't start on windows server

Tags: apache, windows-server-2008, windows-server

We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition. We have Apache 2.2 on it.

Whether I try to start him from the command line or via the Server Manager, I get this error

"*A service specific error occurred: 1.*"

Google, Bing, and Yahoo found me sites that say this means that apache tried to access a file in a folder which doesn’t exist. (Is that true ?) Following that lead, more googling told me that I would find the culprit(s) in an error log file, purportedly on my server, in this subdirectory...

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>
```

There is no record of my errors in any of the files in that subdirectory. There are, however, records of errors in the *error.log* file from two and three weeks ago.  This, despite the fact that I can create that very error as many times as I want right here and now.

Immediate question: Where do I find the log of the errors that I have been creating today ?

Real question: why won't Apache start on my Windows Server ?

Answer (score 1):

In conf folder, there should be file that tells Apache which port to run on.  Make sure nothing else is on that port.

Comment: Give me an idea of what I'm looking for. What is good ? What is bad ? Who are the common culprits ? And thank you for your response. Oh, what is the name of that file ?

Comment: Okay, found the file "httpd.conf" and looked in it. He's listening on port 80. What do I do ?

Comment: Try ctrl H to find and replace all 80 with something like 444 or some other (presumably) empty port.  You should be able to check to see which ports are active in the server manager.

Comment: Server Manager has a lot of options. I'm hunting and pecking to find how to determine what ports are used for what. Clues would be welcomed

Comment: @Mallanga, searched the entire httpd.conf file and found only one reference to the two digits "80" in the entire file. Can I use the "netstat -ao" (no quotes) command to help me guess an unused port to which I should assign the "Listen" command in the httpd.conf file ?

Comment: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ that's kind of cool.  In my experience with apache, something is using it to respond to requests for data.  What do you need apache for?  What is using it, and where is that application's .conf file?

Comment: SVN (Subversion) is using Apache

Comment: http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Enable_HTTP_and_HTTPS_access_for_Subversion - you see that article?  mentions port configuration.  looks like that httpd.conf file is the right one.  just change the ports from 80 to 8000 and try to start it again.